# Process ends with 100% progress and error while using pre-signed url for images

Tags: autodesk-realitycapture

*Using Mac, language .NET*

Photoscene ID : krb1VCLBHop1AdbAdPtm96PWtCfsbncmfSXdSG5eUYM

I'm trying to upload images from *mobile device* to create 3d model of an *object*.
There were some issues uploading local images directly, so I uploaded images on AWS S3 and generated [pre-signed url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html). These urls were used within file uploading *curl* command.

```
curl -v $BASE'photo-to-3d/v1/file' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer '$AUTH 
-F "photosceneid="$PID 
-F "type=image" 
-F "file[0]="$URL
```

the result shows *no error* msg.

```
{"Usage":"2.1651990413666",
"Resource":"\/file",
"photosceneid":"krb1VCLBHop1AdbAdPtm96PWtCfsbncmfSXdSG5eUYM",
"Files":{"file":[{"filename":"YXdzNF9yZXF1ZXN0JlgtQW16LURhdGU9MjAyMTEwMDdUMDY0NTU0WiZYLUFtei1TaWduZWRIZWFkZXJzPWhvc3QmWC1BbXotU2lnbmF0dXJlPWUyMDgyYWE2YjgyNzFmNzk4NTFmNzc3MzkwYmFhN2ExN2FjM2Y5MjJjNjM3NGIyMzg5YWFmN2IwNzE3OTY3MjU=.jpg",
"fileid":"AALxKyQX1tAhcEgbM6w6lITCOHAleS1Dumu6ocy3qaY=-krb1VCLBHop1AdbAdPtm96PWtCfsbncmfSXdSG5eUYM",
"filesize":"187126",
"msg":"No error"}
```

Processing ends with error

```
{"Usage":"0.51469397544861",
"Resource":"\/photoscene\/krb1VCLBHop1AdbAdPtm96PWtCfsbncmfSXdSG5eUYM\/progress",
"Photoscene":{"photosceneid":"krb1VCLBHop1AdbAdPtm96PWtCfsbncmfSXdSG5eUYM",
"progressmsg":"ERROR","progress":"100"}}
```

File links were checked. Images were displayed right and can be downloaded.
Format is jpg.

checked photoscene properties and found error_msg_id
`"error_msg_id":"262"`

the meaning of error code was not found anywhere including [error handling documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/developers_guide/error-codes/)

I don't know what to do from here since error message does not specify what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Please check the content of the photoscene, to see if the images in the photoscene are there or that they are not zero sized (for some reason).
To check the content of the photoscene, use curl -X GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene/$PHOTOSCENEID/properties \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer '$TOKEN
This call is undocumented, but explained in this blog post https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/hitchhikers-guide-reality-capture-api

Comment: @varunpatil I checked the properties and file sizes are not zero. However, I noticed file names are not of the original files. 
(e.g. 0001.jpg => YXdz...gtQW=.jpg) I will have to look up the correct use of presigned url if I'm doing things right. Thx for the comment!

Comment: Did you find out the reason for this? I have the same problem